# I got an IAM username, password account ID. How do I set these credentials in AWS CLI or BOTO3 and download folders from an S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

For the life of me I can't figure out how something so simple is so poorly documented online? Am I stupid or missing something?

My colleague in India told gave me
Username: xxxxx
Password: xxxxx
Account ID: xxxxxx

I need to get these files (like 1000s so I can't manually download them from the AWS web interface which I logged into successfully).

How do log in via CLI or BOTO3?

Literally, every single AWS documentation online shows you how to use secret key and not IAM credentials which is ridiculous.

Comment: Those are console credentials. Login the the AWS console, navigate to IAM, go to your user, then security credentials, and create new keys.

Comment: It says I don't have permission

Comment: Then you will have to talk to the person who gave you the credentials and either ask them for the access key and secret key, or access to the console with permissions to generate an access key and secret key.